# Is it possible to take thread dump of a java process in the container from the host?

Tags: java, docker, docker-container

My java process is running inside the container. Of course I can see that process on host machine and see its pid as well. If jdk is not installed on the cluster but on the host, can I run jstack from the host against the java process in the docker container, using this pid. By the way, I tried it and ran into following error

```
Attaching to process ID 66367, please wait...
Error attaching to process: Doesn't appear to be a HotSpot VM (could not find symbol "gHotSpotVMTypes" in remote process)
sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Doesn't appear to be a HotSpot VM (could not find symbol "gHotSpotVMTypes" in remote process)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.setupVM(HotSpotAgent.java:411)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.go(HotSpotAgent.java:305)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.attach(HotSpotAgent.java:140)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:185)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.execute(Tool.java:118)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.main(JStack.java:92)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.runJStackTool(JStack.java:140)
at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.main(JStack.java:106)
```

Comment: As well as jstack is it possible to run kill -3 pid from the host?

Comment: Yes Mark. Though you can send the signal using docker itself. 
    docker kill --signal SIGQUIT <container-id>

Answer (score 7):

The jstack version you are using needs to come from the exactly same JVM version your software is running.

Running `jstack` within the application container will work.

You can also run `jstack` in remote debugging after activating the remote debugging server / jmx on your software.

Also, if your container doesn't have jstack, you can probably run a container built with the same jvm but ships jstack, in the same pid namespace of your jvm container by running:

`docker run --pid=container:your_app your_jstack_images jstack $in_your_app_container_jvms_pid`

Comment: This is genius. $in_your_app_container_jvms_pid usually is just 1.

Comment: I don't understand what the run command does: does it just run jstack? And what's the container, your_app your_jstack_images (do I need to create a new image?). Thanks!

Comment: This runs a new container that shares the PID namespace with `your_app` container (meaning, for example `ps` in both container will have the same result, though, they are different container). You run this container with the same image which ships a JRE, which includes jstack.